# SPSS Python - adding an 'IF' Statement

Tags: python, spss

I am very new to python so please forgive me for any terminology errors.

I have this python code I found on https://www.spss-tutorials.com/apply-dictionary-information-from-excel/

It partially works at the moment, so all i need help with is amending it slightly.

The excel data file I am using is set up in the following way and the python program I am using is below that.

```
Column1      Column2   Column3  column4          Column5             Column6
University1  Variable1   data     data    unique_Variable_label      data
University1  Variable2   data     data    unique_Variable_label      data
University2  Variable1   data     data    unique_Variable_label      data
University2  Variable2   data     data    unique_Variable_label      data



begin program.
xlsPath = r'C:\Users\******\Desktop\Python_SPSS_Labels-temp.xlsx'
import xlrd
varLabCmd = ''
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsPath)
varLabs = wb.sheets()[0]
for rowCnt in range(varLabs.nrows):
    rowVals = varLabs.row_values(rowCnt)
    varLabCmd += "variable labels %s '%s'.\n"%(rowVals[1],rowVals[4].replace("'","''"))
print varLabCmd
end program.
```

At the moment the python program looks at Column2 and finds the corresponding value in Column5 and then adds that into the SPSS syntax which you can see on the eighth line of the Python program.

The data in Column1 specifies the names of different universities. Column2 specifies variable names that i am using in SPSS. Column5 is the appropriate variable label for each university for that variable name.

## What i need to do

I need to amend the python program to first examine column1 and if it is the university that i want, it proceeds to take the corresponding values for column5.

I think it means i need to set a "global variable" where i can specify the university that i want to use, so please would you be able to tell me how to do that as well.

Thank you in advance! :-)

Comment: Do you need to use the approach you listed or was this what you found when looking for a solution?

Comment: Hi, i am only using this solution because it is what i found. I am definitely open to other solutions. thanks.